# How to change the size of the institutional logo on Lyx- breamer?

Tags: beamer, lyx

I tried to use the following codes to insert logo in to my `beamer`, but they dont work with  LyX.

> If you have a file called "institution-logo-filename.xxx", where xxx
>   is a graphic format that can be processed by latex or pdflatex, resp.,
>   then you can add a logo by uncommenting the following:
>
> ```
> %\pgfdeclareimage[height=0.5cm]{institution-logo}{institution-logo-filename.JPG}
> ```

I end up by using  `\titlegraphic{\includegraphics{uni-logo-filename}}`

How to change the size of the institutional logo on LyX/`beamer` using above codes?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Jubobs For LyX, it is sometimes not easy to provide compilable code starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` because [LyX is not a LaTeX editor but a document processor that can generate LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28822/24449). -- In this case, it would be helpful to mention that the LyX template "beamer-conference-ornate-20min.lyx" was used (probably)...

Answer (score 2):

`\includegraphics` takes an optional argument where you can specify width and/or height, as in the `\pgfdeclareimage` code. Hence you can write

```
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{uni-logo-filename}}
```