# Use glossary in Lyx

Tags: lyx

I'm writing my thesis and have to use a LyX-template which uses the glossary package. When creating the PDF in LyX there is no error but also no glossary?

I check my document against the description here:
https://secure.mario-konrad.ch/wiki/doku.php?id=latex:glossary (last example)

The interesting point the execution chain of compiling:

```
$ latex example.tex
$ makeindex example.glo -s example.ist -t example.glg -o example.gls
$ latex example.tex
$ dvips example.dvi -o example.ps
```

Does anybody know how to configure LyX to do the compilation in this order?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: As stated on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossary) the package `glossary` should not be used anymore and the `glossaries` package should be used instead. Check my answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99664/24449). To omit the acronyms list, just ignore the `\newglossaryentry{...}{type=\acronymtype...` and the `\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]`.

Comment: Hi, I followed the instructions and created the bat file changed the converter command an added the example acronym. The acronym is correctly resolved but the acronym-glossary is still missing...?!
If I got it right I should use `\newglossaryentry{api}´ (what I have done for testing). When this will work someday is there a wy to "recycle" the old command of ´\newacronym{}{}{}´?

Comment: @JimBob Actually, "converter" refers to something different in LyX. But if you changed the "Nomenclature command" then it is alright. Does your document contain the two `\printglossary...` commands? There is also an [example given](http://pastebin.com/YJAkw70s). Is it working? - To your second question: It is possible according to [this documentation on how to upgrade from `glossary` to `glossaries`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossary2glossaries.pdf). You might replace `\newacronym` with `\oldacronym` to get the old functionality.

Comment: Hi again! Sorry for delay! Even the example isn't working. It converts without errors but the glossaries are missing. Oviously the bat file is the reason. I copied the 2 line. Do I have to mind something additionally by side of changing the output command?

Comment: @JimBob Oops, I did not see your comment... Please use `@e-birk` to notify me. Otherwise I get notifications only about answers and comments to my own questions and comments to my own answers.

Comment: @JimBob The script `makeglossaries` is a Perl script. Do you have Perl installed (also mentioned in a comment [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25950/24449)? Furthermore, as said the ".bat" file was not tested. For me, following seems to work `FOR /F %%i in ("%1") do makeglossaries %%~ni`. Maybe the full path of the file `makeglossaries` has to be added...

Comment: An alternative without Perl is by using "makeindex" as shown in section "Using makeindex explicitly" of the [glossaries doc](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf). Then the `.bat` file consists of the two lines: `FOR /F %%i in ("%1") do C:\texlive\2012\bin\win32\makeindex.exe -s %%~ni.ist -t %%~ni.glg -o %%~ni.gls %%~ni.glo` and `FOR /F %%i in ("%1") do C:\texlive\2012\bin\win32\makeindex.exe -s %%~ni.ist -t %%~ni.alg -o %%~ni.acr %%~ni.acn`. (Please adjust the path of "makeindex" such that it points to `makeindex.exe` in your system!)