# Getting "description key required in \newglossaryentry" although it exists

Tags: glossaries

I am getting description key required in \newglossaryentry while compiling the example of this Question:
[How to combine Acronym and Glossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8946/how-to-combine-acronym-and-glossary)

I am useing MiKTeX and i compile it with this Script:

```
latex MyFile
makeindex -s -s "%bm.ist" -t "%bm.glg" -o "%bm.gls" "%bm.glo"
makeglossaries MyFile
latex MyFile
latex MyFile
```

**SOLVED:**
i had to delete my old index files:

```
#Delete Litter
rm *.log
rm *.aux
rm *.out
rm *.toc
rm MyFile.ps
rm *.dvi
rm *.acn
rm *.bbl
rm *.blg
rm *.glo
rm *.ist
rm *.lof
rm *.lot
```

Comment: why do you call makeindex with options and then additionally the makeglossaries script? maybe this causes a conflict of some sort. I ran the very last example from my accepted question and get no warning or error (texlive 2010, kile)

Comment: i now have solved it. i had to delete my litter.