# Latex decides to ignore see attribute to \newglossaryentry when using enabling nonumberlist on glossaries package

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

The weirdest thing happened to me today:

I was looking for a way to link from an abbreviation to a glossary entry and found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8951/3870). When emulating it in my code, it did not work - `pdflatex` would ignore the `see` attribute.

Fiddling around, I discovered that this only happens when the `glossaries` package is included with the `nonumberlist` attribute - something that should have no influence whatsoever on links.

Minimal code example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[nonumberlist, acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

%%% define the acronym and use the see= option
\newglossaryentry{css}{type=\acronymtype, name={CSS}, description={Cascading Style Sheets}, first={Cascading Style Sheets (CSS)}, see=[Glossary:]{cssg}}
\newglossaryentry{cssg}{name={Cascading Style Sheets},
                     description={A language for specifying presentation      attributed of XML documents.}}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

% Acronyms
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

% Glossary
\printglossary[style=altlist,title=Glossary]

\end{document}
```

How can I fix this? And why is this even happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented behaviour. Quoting from [the manual](https://www.aq-test.com/latex/texmf-dist/doc/latex/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf):

> **nonumberlist** This option will suppress the associated number lists in the glossaries (see also Section 5).

> **seeautonumberlist** If you suppress the number lists with **nonumberlist**, described above, this will also suppress any
> cross-referencing information supplied by the see key in
> `\newglossaryentry` or `\glssee`. If you use **seeautonumberlist**, the see
> key will automatically implement `nonumberlist=false` for that entry.
> (Note this doesn’t affect `\glssee`.) For further details see Section 8.

So a possible solution is to also set `seeautonumberlist`. This may have the undesired effect that the acronym entry now gets the page number that you wanted to avoid with `nonumberlist` in the first place:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,seeautonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

%%% define the acronym and use the see= option
\newglossaryentry{css}{
  type=\acronymtype,
  name={CSS},
  description={Cascading Style Sheets},
  first={Cascading Style Sheets (CSS)},
  see=[Glossary:]{cssg}
}
\newglossaryentry{cssg}{
  name={Cascading Style Sheets},
  description={A language for specifying presentation attributed of XML documents}
}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

% Acronyms
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

% Glossary
\printglossary[style=altlist,title=Glossary]

\end{document}
```

An alternative is to add the reference manually to the description of the acronym. This way you also don't get the page number in the acronym entry:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

%%% define the acronym
\newglossaryentry{css}{
  type=\acronymtype,
  name={CSS},
  description={Cascading Style Sheets. \textit{Glossary:} \gls{cssg}},
  first={Cascading Style Sheets (CSS)}
}
\newglossaryentry{cssg}{
  name={Cascading Style Sheets},
  description={A language for specifying presentation attributed of XML documents}
}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

% Acronyms
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

% Glossary
\printglossary[style=altlist,title=Glossary]

\end{document}
```