# How to combine Acronym and Glossary?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to combine Acronym and Glossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8946/how-to-combine-acronym-and-glossary)

I'm using glossaries in LaTeX.

I have an acronym (e.g. *API*) that should be explained in the glossary.
Every occurrence of it should be linked to the glossary, and the very first occurrence should be expanded to the full form.

How can I do that?

Comment: i will try to do that.

Comment: The link to the answer on tex.stackexchange.com will be helpful to others. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8946/how-to-combine-acronym-and-glossary

Comment: I know, I added the link so people don't need to go searching for the answer on that site and also so that your question goes off the unanswered list.