# Glossaries creates wrong link when using titlepage

Tags: titles, glossaries, links

mI experienced that glossaries generates a wrong link when my document contains a titlepage...

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{api}{type=\acronymtype, name={API}, description={Application
Programming Interface}, first={Application
Programming Interface (API)}, see=[Glossary:]{apig}}

\newglossaryentry{apig}{name={API},
description={An Application Programming Interface (API) is a particular set
of rules and specifications that a software program can follow to access and
make use of the services and resources provided by another particular     software
program that implements that API},nonumberlist}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\center{title}
\end{titlepage}
\newpage
\noindent
First use \gls{api}\\
subsequent \gls{api}
\newpage
a page between
\newpage
Another use: \gls{api}\\
\newpage

\glsadd{apig}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\newpage
\printglossary[type=main]

\end{document}
```

I took the code from here:
[How to combine Acronym and Glossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8946/how-to-combine-acronym-and-glossary)

I want to have acronyms and a glossary.
And the acronyms should link to the glossary...

I won't mind to remove the page number behind the acronym, but using the "nonumberlist" option also removes the link to my glossary :-/

Using the code without the titlepage works fine...

Thanks for help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: The problem is that you have two pages "number 1". A workaround is to say `\pagenumbering{alph}` before the `titlepage` and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` just after it.

Comment: Damn^^ I just found that a few seconds ago and was trying to post an answer for my own question.. Thank you anyway :) How can I set your answer to be the best and close this "topic" ?

Comment: you might be able to delete the question, or else head into the chat room and find a moderator who could close it- I'll flag it for moderator attention too; glad you got it fixed :)