# Makeindex-style for list of acronyms (glossaries)

Tags: texlive, glossaries, acronyms, xindy

I'm a LaTeX newbie using [*this example*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8951) provieded by [*Tom Brien*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/46863/tom-brien) to combine some of my acronyms with their glossaries-entries. I would like to change the style of the acronyms-list to make it looks like this:
[image]

I tried to change the style using this command:

```
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long3col]
```

Now my list looks like this:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries


%%% The glossary entry the acronym links to   
\newglossaryentry{apig}{name={API},
    description={An Application Programming Interface (API) is a particular set
of rules and specifications that a software program can follow to access and
make use of the services and resources provided by another particular software
program that implements that API}}

%%% define the acronym and use the see= option
\newglossaryentry{api}{type=\acronymtype, name={API}, description={Application
Programming Interface}, first={Application
Programming Interface (API)\glsadd{apig}}, see=[Glossary:]{apig}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
First use \gls{api}\\
subsequent \gls{api}
\newpage

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long3col]
%%% \newpage just to demonstrate that links are correct
\newpage
\printglossary[type=main]

\end{document}
```

What have I to change in the code to make it looks like in picture above?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: ok I added the code above :-)

Answer (score 3):

The `see` key always puts the cross-reference at the end of the location list, so I think it's better to move the cross-reference into the end of the description, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{longdotted}{%
 \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\dotfill ##2\tabularnewline
  }%
}

\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.85\hsize}

%%% The glossary entry the acronym links to   
\newglossaryentry{apig}{name={API},
    description={An Application Programming Interface (API) is a particular set
of rules and specifications that a software program can follow to access and
make use of the services and resources provided by another particular software
program that implements that API}}

%%% define the acronym and use the see= option
\newglossaryentry{api}{type=\acronymtype, name={API}, description={Application
Programming Interface \emph{Glossary:} \glsname{apig}}, first={Application
Programming Interface (API)\glsadd{apig}}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
First use \gls{api}\\
subsequent \gls{api}
\newpage

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=longdotted]
%%% \newpage just to demonstrate that links are correct
\newpage
\printglossary[type=main]

\end{document}
```

This looks like:

[image: image of glossary with dotted leader]

You may need to change the value of `\glsdescwidth`.

Another possibility is to use the extension package `glossaries-extra`, which stores the value of the `see` key. (The base `glossaries` package doesn't do this. There the `see` key simply triggers `\glssee`.) The `see` value can be accessed with `\glsxtrusesee{`*label*`}`, so the glossary style can be adapted so that it places the cross-reference in the desired place. For example:

```
\newglossarystyle{longdotted}{%
 \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription
     \space\glsxtrusesee{##1}% add cross-reference
     \dotfill ##2\tabularnewline
  }%
}
```

The only problem now is to prevent the automatic `\glssee` that occurs when the `see` field is detected when entries are defined. There are two ways to do this.

The first method requires `glossaries-extra` v1.16, which is new and so may not be available. This version provides the `autoseeindex` package option, which governs the automatic use of `\glssee`. The option `autoseeindex=false` has the side-effect of not switching on the `indexcrossrefs` option, so that needs to be done explicitly:

```
\usepackage[acronym,
 autoseeindex=false,% store see key but don't automatically add to location list
 indexcrossrefs% index the cross-referenced terms
]{glossaries-extra}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,
 autoseeindex=false,% store see key but don't automatically add to location list
 indexcrossrefs% index the cross-referenced terms
]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{longdotted}{%
 \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription
     \space\glsxtrusesee{##1}% add cross-reference
     \dotfill ##2\tabularnewline
  }%
}

\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.85\hsize}

%%% The glossary entry the acronym links to   
\newglossaryentry{apig}{name={API},
    description={An Application Programming Interface (API) is a particular set
of rules and specifications that a software program can follow to access and
make use of the services and resources provided by another particular software
program that implements that API}}

%%% define the acronym and use the see= option
\newglossaryentry{api}{type=\acronymtype, 
 name={API},
 see=[Glossary:]{apig},
 description={Application Programming Interface},
 first={Application Programming Interface (API)}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
First use \gls{api}\\
subsequent \gls{api}
\newpage

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=longdotted]
%%% \newpage just to demonstrate that links are correct
\newpage
\printglossary[type=main]

\end{document}
```

The second method is to put `\makeglossaries` after the entry definitions. This command opens the external glossary files ready for indexing. Any indexing that occurs before that command can't be implemented as the appropriate file isn't open. Since this isn't usually desired, the `glossaries` package will produce an error if `see` is used before `\makeglossaries`. This error can be turned to a warning with the package option `seenoindex=warn` or simply ignored with `seenoindex=ignore`. (This option was new to `glossaries` v4.24):

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,
 seenoindex=ignore% ignore 'see' key occurring before \makeglossaries
]{glossaries-extra}


\newglossarystyle{longdotted}{%
 \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription
     \space\glsxtrusesee{##1}% add cross-reference
     \dotfill ##2\tabularnewline
  }%
}

\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.85\hsize}

%%% The glossary entry the acronym links to   
\newglossaryentry{apig}{name={API},
    description={An Application Programming Interface (API) is a particular set
of rules and specifications that a software program can follow to access and
make use of the services and resources provided by another particular software
program that implements that API}}

%%% define the acronym and use the see= option
\newglossaryentry{api}{type=\acronymtype, 
 name={API},
 see=[Glossary:]{apig},
 description={Application Programming Interface},
 first={Application Programming Interface (API)}}

\makeglossaries % open external files for indexing

\begin{document}
\noindent
First use \gls{api}\\
subsequent \gls{api}
\newpage

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=longdotted]
%%% \newpage just to demonstrate that links are correct
\newpage
\printglossary[type=main]

\end{document}
```

There's a further modification that can be made. At the moment, the tag `Glossary:` needs to be added to each instance of the `see` key (as in `see=[Glossary:]{apig}`). If this needs to be done for every entry in the `acronym` glossary, then it would be more convenient so set this tag in the cross-reference format. With the base `glossaries` package, there are two ways of doing this: redefined `\seename` or redefine `\glsseeformat`. I don't recommend the former as this will cause a problem if the document also needs an index.

`\glsseeformat` has an optional argument which is the tag, and is defined as:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\glsseeformat}[3][\seename]{%
  \emph{#1} \glsseelist{#2}}
```

It's rarely used without the optional argument and `see={apig}` will end up as `\glsseeformat[\seename]{apig}{}`, so the altered version will need the tag explicitly in the definition:

```
\renewrobustcmd*{\glsseeformat}[3][\seename]{%
  \emph{Glossary:} \glsseelist{#2}}
```

(or add a test for `\seename` as `#1`).

If you have `glossaries-extra` v1.16, there's another alternative and that's to use the `seealso` key instead of the `see` key. The `seealso` key doesn't allow the optional tag part at the start of the cross-reference label list. The associated formatting is `\glsxtruseseealsoformat` which is defined as:

```
\newcommand*{\glsxtruseseealsoformat}[1]{%
  \glsseeformat[\seealsoname]{#1}{}%
}
```

This can be redefined to use your custom tag:

```
\renewcommand*{\glsxtruseseealsoformat}[1]{%
  \glsseeformat[Glossary:]{#1}{}%
}
```

Any other cross-references that shouldn't have this tag can then be performed as normal with the `see` key.