# Spurious comma by use of \glsaddallunused

Tags: glossaries

I am compiling the following document with glossaries v4.11:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{foo}{name={foo},description={Foo}}
\newglossaryentry{bar}{name={bar},description={Bar}}
\newglossaryentry{baz}{name={baz},description={Baz}}

\begin{document}

\gls{foo} \glsadd{bar}

\printglossaries

\glsaddallunused

\end{document}
```

The entries "foo" and "baz" appear as intended, but there is a spurious comma in the "bar" entry that was added using `\glsadd`:

[image: glossary with spurious comma]

Removing `\glsaddallunused` fixes the problem, but then the "baz" entry does not appear any more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The entry `bar` is added twice without using it by `\glsadd{bar}` and `\glsaddallunused`. In the description of the latter, the documentation says:

> If you want to use `\glsaddallunused`, it's best to place the command
>   at the end of the document to ensure that all the commands you intend
>   to use have already been used. Otherwise you could end up with a
>   spurious comma or dash in the location list.

Apparently, this also applies, when an entry is added twice.

Possible workaround: Using `bar` by putting it in an unused box: `\sbox0{\gls{bar}}` or `\glsunset{bar}` to mark it used:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{foo}{name={foo},description={Foo}}
\newglossaryentry{bar}{name={bar},description={Bar}}
\newglossaryentry{baz}{name={baz},description={Baz}}

\begin{document}

\gls{foo} \glsadd{bar}\glsunset{bar}

\printglossaries

\glsaddallunused

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: @SörenSchulze `\sbox0{\gls{bar}}` is intended as addition to `\glsadd{bar}`. The command for this purpose is `\glsunset` if I have understood the documentation correctly. Answer updated.