# Comma in Glossary when Referring to Glossary Entry in Glossary Entry

Tags: glossaries

## Question

I have these glossary entries:

[image]

I just created the document and it is empty except for test text and a few definitions. The glossary is on page 3. As you can see, there is a comma before the page numbers linking to where the entries have been referred to for `Datenobjekt` and `Objekt`. You can also see that `Objekt` refers to `Datenobjekt`.

On my search for a solution, I came across [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253308/spurious-comma-by-use-of-glsaddallunused). `\glsaddallunused` already is at the end of the document and when I created test text referring to `passives Objekt` (which isn't referred to by a different glossary entry), no comma appeared before the page number. So it seems to be caused by referring to a glossary entry in a glossary entry and calling `\glsaddallunused` in the document.

How can the commas be removed?

---

## Example Document

I cut my document down content-wise as much as possible without breaking any reference dependencies and removed all other command definitions.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 10in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}

\title{UTF-8's Example Document}
\author{UTF-8}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=black,
    pdftitle={\@title},
    pdfauthor={\@author},
    bookmarks=true
}

\newcommand{\glsquotation}[1]{
    \paragraph{\gls{#1}:} \glsdesc*{#1}.
}


\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{Objekt}
{
    name=Objekt,
    plural=Objekte,
    description={Siehe \gls{Datenobjekt}},
}

\newglossaryentry{Datenobjekt}
{
    name=Datenobjekt,
    plural=Datenobjekte,
    description={Repräsentiert Informationen},
}

\newglossaryentry{Subjekt}
{
    name=Subjekt,
    plural=Subjekte,
    description={Benutzer eines Systems oder Objekt, das im Auftrag von Benutzern im System aktiv sein kann (z.B. Prozess, Server, Prozedur)},
}

\newglossaryentry{Autorisierung}
{
    name=Autorisierung,
    plural=Autorisierungen,
    description={Besitzt ein \gls{Subjekt} die Berechtigung, auf ein \gls{Objekt} zuzugreifen, so nennt man das Subjekt für diesen Datenzugriff autorisiert},
}

\newglossaryentry{Authentizitaet}
{
    name=Authentizität,
    plural=Authentizitäten,
    description={Echtheit und Glaubwürdigkeit eines \glslink{Objekt}{Objekts} bzw. \glslink{Subjekt}{Subjekts}, die anhand seiner Identität und seiner charakteristischen Eigenschaften überprüfbar ist},
}

\newglossaryentry{vertraulich}
{
    name=vertraulich,
    description={System ermöglicht keine \glslink{Autorisierung}{unautorisierte} Informationsgewinnung},
}

\newglossaryentry{integer}
{
    name=integer,
    description={Subjekten ist es nicht möglich, Daten \glslink{Autorisierung}{unautorisiert} und unbemerkt zu manipulieren},
}

\newglossaryentry{verfuegbar}
{
    name=verfügbar,
    description={Authentifizierte und \glslink{Autorisierung}{autorisierte} \glspl{Subjekt} werden in der Wahrnehmung ihrer Berechtigungen nicht \glslink{Autorisierung}{unautorisiert} beeinträchtigt},
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\glsquotation{Authentizitaet}\\

Das klassische Schutzziel-Trio besteht aus Vertraulichkeit, Integrität, und Verfügbarkeit:

\glsquotation{vertraulich}
\glsquotation{integer}
\glsquotation{verfuegbar}


\glsaddallunused
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

I wrote this script to build it (but you obviously can't use the cleaning option without the cleaning script):

```
# Builds the document specified by 'documentname'.
# Call with option '-c' or '--clean' to clean the top-levl directory before building.

#!/bin/bash

# CONFIGURATION
documentname="ENTER WHAT YOU CALLED THE FILE HERE (WITHOUT FILE EXTENSION)"
# END OF CONFUGURATION

if [ $1 == "-c" ] || [ $1 == "--clean" ]; then
    ./clean.sh
fi


pdflatex "$documentname.tex"
makeglossaries "$documentname"
pdflatex "$documentname.tex"
pdflatex "$documentname.tex"
makeindex -s "$documentname.ist" -o "$documentname.gls" "$documentname.glo"
pdflatex "$documentname.tex"
echo finished
sleep 2
```

Comment: Please provide a complete small document, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that illustrates your problem. Without this information, it is hard/impossible to analyze the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have to use `\glsaddallunused`.  And from what I can tell you don't need to.

You found that some of your terms, i.e. `Datenobjekt` weren't showing up in your glossary because it wasn't explicitly used, only used in the initialization of another term.

The only issue you have here is that `makeindex` is not an infinitely recursive/iterative process.

If you simply add `makeindex` calls for any glossary that uses recursive terms you can continue to use `\gls{Datenobjekt}` or `\glslink{Datenobjekt}{Datenobjekt}` in your `\newglossaryentry`

For example, I can compile your document (commenting out only the `%\glsaddallunused`) and compiling (on my `MikTeX` machine) using my own little compilation script:

```
:CheckOS
IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="x86" (GOTO 32BIT) ELSE (GOTO 64BIT)

:64BIT
ECHO 64-bit compiling
SET MikTexPath=C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\
GOTO END

:32BIT
ECHO 32-bit compiling
SET MikTexPath=C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\
GOTO END

:END

SET TeXCompilier=xelatex.exe

FOR %%A IN (*.tex) DO (
"%MikTexPath%%TeXCompilier%" "%%~nxA" &_
call BibTeXBuild.bat &_
"%MikTexPath%makeindex.exe" -s "%%~nA.ist" -t "%%~nA.glg" -o "%%~nA.gls" "%%~nA.glo" &_
"%MikTexPath%makeindex.exe" -s "%%~nA.ist" -t "%%~nA.alg" -o "%%~nA.acr" "%%~nA.acn" &_
"%MikTexPath%%TeXCompilier%" "%%~nxA" &_
"%MikTexPath%makeindex.exe" -s "%%~nA.ist" -t "%%~nA.glg" -o "%%~nA.gls" "%%~nA.glo" &_
"%MikTexPath%makeindex.exe" -s "%%~nA.ist" -t "%%~nA.alg" -o "%%~nA.acr" "%%~nA.acn" &_
"%MikTexPath%%TeXCompilier%" "%%~nxA" &_
"%MikTexPath%%TeXCompilier%" "%%~nxA" &_
"%MikTexPath%%TeXCompilier%" "%%~nxA" &_
)
```

I don't have any problem with the page references running my script, so possibly changing your script to the following (untested) might work:

```
# Builds the document specified by 'documentname'.
# Call with option '-c' or '--clean' to clean the top-levl directory before building.

#!/bin/bash

# CONFIGURATION
documentname="ENTER WHAT YOU CALLED THE FILE HERE (WITHOUT FILE EXTENSION)"
# END OF CONFUGURATION

if [ $1 == "-c" ] || [ $1 == "--clean" ]; then
    ./clean.sh
fi


pdflatex "$documentname.tex"
makeglossaries "$documentname"
makeindex -s "$documentname.ist" -o "$documentname.gls" "$documentname.glo"
pdflatex "$documentname.tex"
makeglossaries "$documentname"
makeindex -s "$documentname.ist" -o "$documentname.gls" "$documentname.glo"
pdflatex "$documentname.tex"
pdflatex "$documentname.tex"
pdflatex "$documentname.tex"
echo finished
sleep 2
```