# Why acronym appears under glossary?

Tags: table-of-contents, glossaries, acronyms

Here is minimum working example:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {action: nonstopmode}
% !arara: makeindex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex: {action: nonstopmode}
% arara: pdflatex: {action: nonstopmode}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[slovak,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% HEADER AND FOOTER
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% THIS SHOULD BE DEFINED BEFORE glossaries
% COMPILATION ERROR IF THOSE TWO LINES ARE SWAPPED
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% WORKING
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

% DOES NOT WORKING:
% Package glossaries Error: Glossary type `acronym' has not been defined. }
% \usepackage{glossaries}

% Unknown option `intoc' for package `glossaries'. \RequirePackage
% \usepackage[intoc]{glossaries}

% Package glossaries Error: Glossary type `acronym' has not been defined. }
% \usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% USING PICTURES
\usepackage{graphicx}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% WHAT DOES THIS DO ???
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% SETTING HEADER AND FOOTER
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{LHEAD}
\rhead{RHEAD}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% default is 0pt
\cfoot{\thepage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{setspace}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers,square,comma,numbers]{natbib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% TABLE OF CONTENT
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\settocbibname{References}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% DOES NOT WORK: CONTENTS NAME REMAINS "Contents" INSTEAD OF "Table of Contents"
\settocname{Table of Contents}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% DOES NOT WORK: INITIAL NUMBER BELLOW FOOTER REMAINS ALWAYS THE SAME (NUMBER OF PAGES BEFORE PARTICULAR SHEET - 1)
\setcounter{page}{10}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{10}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% SET MAX CONTENTS DEPTH
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\citefull}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}~(\citeyear{#1})~\cite{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\citefulle}[1]{[\citeauthor{#1}~(\citeyear{#1})~\cite{#1}]}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\citebegin}[1]{In \citeyear{#1} \citeauthor{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\citeaccord}[1]{According to \citeyear{#1} \citeauthor{#1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
  \input{glossary.tex}
  \input{acronyms.tex}

  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    {\scshape\LARGE University\\
                    Faculty\par}
    \vspace{5cm}
    {\huge\bfseries Thesis Name\par}
    \vspace{1.0cm}
    {\scshape\Large Thesis submitted for the degree of\\
                    Academic Degree\par}
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\Large\itshape Author\par}
    \vfill
    supervised by\par
    ~Supervisor
    \vfill
    {\large \today\par}
  \end{titlepage}
  \pagebreak
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{doublespace}
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Abstract}
    \selectlanguage{slovak}
    \input{abstract_svk.tex}
    \pagebreak
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \selectlanguage{english}
    \input{abstract_eng.tex}
    \pagebreak
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}
    \begin{abstract}
      Graditude
    \end{abstract}
    \pagebreak
  \end{doublespace}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% TABLE OF CONTENT
  \thispagestyle{empty}  
  \tableofcontents
  \pagebreak
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% LIST OF FIGURES
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \listoffigures
  \pagebreak
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% ACRONYMS
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
  \newpage
% GLOSSARY
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \printglossary[type=main]
  \newpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \begin{doublespace}
    % This returns: "First use Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) subsequent UTC"
    First use \gls{utc} subsequent \gls{utc}

    % This returns: "First use Application Programming Interface (API) subsequent API"
    % In this example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8946/how-to-combine-acronym-and-glossary there is also refernce from Acronyms to Glossary
    First use \gls{api} subsequent \gls{api}

    % Why this one appears in Glossary instead of Acronyms?
    % Why this one is shown in Glossary as "Intrusion detection and prevention systems" instead of "Intrusion Detection and Prevention Systems" (case difference)?
    % Why this returns: "First use IDPS subsequent IDPS" instead of "First use Intrusion Detection and Prevention Systems (IDPS) subsequent IDPS" ?
    First use \gls{idps} subsequent \gls{idps}

    \input{1.tex}
    \pagebreak

    \input{2.tex}
    \pagebreak

    \input{3.tex}
    \pagebreak

  \end{doublespace}
  \pagebreak
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
  \bibliography{mendeley-13-01-29}
\end{document}
```

Here is glossary.tex:

```
\newglossaryentry{apig}{
        name={API},
        description={An Application Programming Interface (API) is a
                    particular set
                    of rules and specifications that a software program can
                    follow to access and make use of the services and
                    resources provided by another particular software
                    program that implements that API}
    }
```

Here is acronyms.tex:

```
\newacronym{utc}{UTC}{Coordinated Universal Time}


\newglossaryentry{api}{
        type=\acronymtype,
        name={API},
        description={Application Programming Interface},
        first={Application Programming Interface (API)\glsadd{apig}},
        see=[Glossary:]{apig}
        }

\newglossaryentry{idps}{
        type=\acronymtype,
        name={IDPS},
        description={Intrusion Detection and Prevention Systems},
        first={Intrusion Detection and Prevention Systems (IDPS)}
        }
```

As you can see I'm using arara for compilation. My goal is to have both Acronyms and Glossary in document. Questions:

1. Regarding this line: `First use \gls{idps} subsequent \gls{idps}`
   Why this one appears in Glossary instead of Acronyms? Why this one is shown (in Glossary) as "Intrusion detection and prevention systems" instead of "Intrusion Detection and Prevention Systems" (case difference)? Why this returns: "First use IDPS subsequent IDPS" instead of "First use Intrusion Detection and Prevention Systems (IDPS) subsequent IDPS" as it is in 2nd and 3rd question?
2. Regarding this line: `First use \gls{api} subsequent \gls{api}` In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8946/how-to-combine-acronym-and-glossary) example there is also reference from Acronyms to Glossary, why it is not working in my example?
3. Regarding this line: `First use \gls{utc} subsequent \gls{utc}` Should I use `\newacronym` over `newglossaryentry`?
4. <strike>How can I include both Acronyms and Glossary in Contents? I've tried several things (see my comments in code) but neither worked.</strike>

Thank you very much

Comment: That is not at all minimal. Please post a *minimal* example and ask one question per question.

Comment: Why it is not minimal? I've posted it in context in which I want to use it (with footers, headers, front page etc.). The question is why acronym appears under glossary? I've added another questions to show that in original document where I'm referencing it is working while in mine it is not, maybe it is related somehow I do not know. Please do not consider them as questions but rather my observations that might help solve the problem. Thank you

Comment: A minimal example contains just enough to reproduce the problem.  For some help in what an MWE needs to contain, as well as instructions for constructing one, see [this question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal example which uses your acronym and glossary definitions in a minimal wrapper. Both are added to the contents and the cross-referencing seems to work fine.

[image: glossary and acronyms]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{apig}{
  name={API},
  description={An Application Programming Interface (API) is a particular set of rules and specifications that a software program can follow to access and make use of the services and resources provided by another particular software program that implements that API}
}
\newacronym{utc}{UTC}{Coordinated Universal Time}
\newglossaryentry{api}{
  type=\acronymtype,
  name={API},
  description={Application Programming Interface},
  first={Application Programming Interface (API)\glsadd{apig}},
  see=[Glossary:]{apig}
}
\newglossaryentry{idps}{
  type=\acronymtype,
  name={IDPS},
  description={Intrusion Detection and Prevention Systems},
  first={Intrusion Detection and Prevention Systems (IDPS)}
}
\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents

  \section{First}

  \gls{utc}

  \gls{idps}

  \gls{api}

  \section{Subsequent}

  \gls{utc}

  \gls{idps}

  \gls{api}

\printglossary
\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

Comment: So what I did wrong, why your example is working and mine not? Our code base looks similar. In your code IDPS is correctly added under Acronyms with proper case, also the first occurrence in text is with full description and subsequent occurrences are with acronyms. Referencing from Acronyms to Glossary is working also (API example). Thank you

Comment: Seems that putting `\input{glossary.tex}` and `\input{acronyms.tex}` right after `\makeglossaries` instead under `\begin{document}` Did the trick

Comment: Why aren't you using `\loadglsentries{}{}` and friends?

Comment: Because here http://malcolmkeating.blogspot.sk/2013/08/using-glossary-package-in-latex.html it is said that it is from Glossary package and here http://texblog.org/2014/01/15/glossary-and-list-of-acronyms-with-latex/ it is said that Glossary is obsolete and replaced by Glossaries

Comment: It is in the documentation for Glossaries. It is the package's method for loading entries from external databases. Regardless of what confusion is being sown. The fact is that two packages can define the same command even if one of them is obsolete but not the other. Read the documentation rather than guessing.