# Trouble making a glossary

Tags: glossaries

I have been trying to make a glossary using the package *glossaries*, I am clearly doing something wrong as I keep gettin errors when compiling the document.

I have the following:

1. Create a document (`glosario.tex`) with all the definitions, for me most of them are acronyms so I have defined them the following way: `\acro{CCTV}{\emph{Close Circuit Television}}`
2. Add the following commands to my preamble:

   ```
   \usepackage[toc]{glossaries} % Load the package with the acronym option
   \makeglossaries{glosario} % Generate the glossary
   \printglossary[type=\acronymtype] % prints just the list of acronyms
   ```

Despite trying several thing this doesn't seem to work. Anyone know what I am doing wrong and how this can be solved?

Comment: `glossaries` doesn't define `\acro`. Also, `\makeglossaries` doesn't have an argument. You need to load `glosario.tex` with `\loadglsentries`. Try the [beginner's guide](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.html) for some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Create a document (glosario.tex) with all the definitions, for me most of them are acronyms so I have defined them the following way: \acro{CCTV}{\emph{Close Circuit Television}}

You seem to be mixing up packages. `glossaries` doesn't define `\acro`.

> \usepackage[toc]{glossaries} % Load the package with the acronym option

This isn't loading the package with the `acronym` option. It's loading it with the `toc` option.

> \makeglossaries{glosario} % Generate the glossary

The `\makeglossaries` command doesn't have an argument

Your `glosario.tex` file needs to be loaded using `\loadglsentries`. Example `glossario.tex`:

```
\newacronym{CCTV}{CCTV}{Closed Circuit Television}
```

Main document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

% Define a style the emphasizes the long form:

\newacronymstyle{em-long-short}
{%
  \GlsUseAcrEntryDispStyle{long-short}%
}%
{%
  \GlsUseAcrStyleDefs{long-short}%  
  \renewcommand*{\genacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \emph{\glsentrylong{##1}}##2\space
   (\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}})%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\Genacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \emph{\Glsentrylong{##1}}##2\space
   (\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}})%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \emph{\glsentrylongpl{##1}}##2\space
   (\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{##1}})%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\Genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \emph{\Glsentrylongpl{##1}}##2\space
   (\firstacronymfont{\Glsentryshortpl{##1}})%
  }%
}

\setacronymstyle{em-long-short}

\loadglsentries{glosario}

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{CCTV}. Next use: \gls{CCTV}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

Steps to build this document: `latex`, `makeglossaries`, `latex` (or `pdflatex` instead of `latex`). If you can't work out how to run `makeglossaries`, just add `automake` to the package option list:

```
\usepackage[automake,toc,acronym]{glossaries}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

Alternatively:

File `glosario.tex`:

```
\newabbreviation{CCTV}{CCTV}{Closed Circuit Television}
```

Main file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[automake,abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}

\renewcommand{\glsfirstlongdefaultfont}[1]{\emph{#1}}

\loadglsentries{glosario}

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{CCTV}. Next use: \gls{CCTV}.

\printabbreviations
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

Comment: The 1st example above gives me the following, No pdf file. Why? `(C:\Full_TeX\texmf\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15
\XKV@depth=\count87
File: xkeyval.tex 2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)

(C:\Full_TeX\texmf\tex\generic\xkeyval\keyval.tex)))

! LaTeX Error: File `mfirstuc.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.

         
l.46 \RequirePackage
                    {textcase}`

Comment: @OlgaK You need to install the `mfirstuc` package. You should be able to do this through your TeX package manager.

Comment: I have MikTex Options - Refresh bases on fly, and normally it downloads and install all packages listed in preambula itself. But not for this case

Comment: I've tried to add `\usepackage{mfirstuc}`, still no result

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I am using the second option which seems to be working a bit better as the first one didn't add the glossary to my document. When using the secon option a new page is added to document saying: "This document is incomplete. The external file associated with the glossaty 'abbreviations' (which should be called JCG_TFG.gls-abr) hasn't been created."

Comment: @OlgaK sometimes the package doesn't install properly or is just ignore, I would recoment you installing it directly from MikTex package manager

Comment: @Neptune That should only occur on the first `latex` run to let you know you haven't completed the build process. If you have the `automake` option or after you run `makeglossaries` it should be fixed on the second `latex` run.