# glossaries automake not working lualatex

Tags: glossaries-extra

I have an up to date MikTex distribution.
Roughly following [Trouble making a glossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305512/trouble-making-a-glossary), I have the following code in test.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{shellesc}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain,toc,automake]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\loadglsentries{glosario}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{CCTV}. Next use: \gls{CCTV}.
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

and glosario.tex containing

```
\newacronym{CCTV}{CCTV}{Closed Circuit Television}
```

This works with `pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex`, however, when I use `lualatex -shell-escape test.tex`, the entries are not found. This is the output

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.09.0 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930 64-bit)
 system commands enabled.
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 1.454 seconds
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/article.cls"
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/size10.clo"))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex"))))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/mfirstuc/mfirstuc.sty")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/xfor/xfor.sty")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-base.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty"
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty"))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty"))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/substr/substr.sty")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-fp.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty"
`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty"))))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries-compatible-3
07.sty")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-hypernav.sty
") ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-list.sty"
) ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-long.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty"))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-super.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/supertabular/supertabular.sty"))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-tree.sty")))
 (./glosario.tex) (./test.aux) (./test.acr)This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9.6930 64-bit] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file ./test.ist.............................done (29 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file test.acn...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in test.acr.
Transcript written in test.alg.
```

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: Your example works for me with TL 2018, with `lualatex`

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on windows, both with miktex and texlive. That's rather curious. (Side remark: --shell-escape shouldn't be needed).

Comment: Without `\usepackage{shellesc}` lualatex is not calling `makeindex` for me.

Comment: I didn't mean the package but the option `--shell-escape`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `automake=immediate` in this situation. (New to `glossaries` version 4.22 2019-01-06.) This executes the system command at the start of `\makeglossaries` (before the glossary files are opened) using `\immediate`. You will get a warning on the first LaTeX run when the files don't exist.

With `automake=true` (or simply `automake`), the system command is executed at the end of the document, but `\immediate` can't be used in this case. Unlike indexes, glossaries may occur at the start of the document rather than the end, and it's possible that there are commands such as `\gls` on the last page. The indexing performed by these commands can't use `\immediate` as it can cause problems with the associated page number due to TeX's asynchronous output routine. If `\write18` is called with `\immediate` in this case, there's a possibility that the system command may be called before the glossary files are complete.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that with luatex (and the shellesc package) `\write18` is actually an `\immediate\write18` (see the documentation of shellesc). And this means that the makeindex command is executed *before* the acn-file has been written and closed. This is imho a bug in glossaries and should be reported.

You can patch the command like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{shellesc}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain,toc,automake]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\loadglsentries{glosario}

\makeglossaries

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@gls@automake{\write18}{\DelayedShellEscape}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\First use: \gls{CCTV}. Next use: \gls{CCTV}.
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

This will also work with pdflatex. You don't need the --shell-escape option, makeindex is in the list of safe applications.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I sent a message to the maintainer.

Comment: As of 2022-06-06, despite the accepted answer, I can only make `automake` work with `luatex` using the `shellesc` functionality and the patch suggested here.

Comment: My previous statement is not correct, using `automake=immediate`, as suggested by Nicola, *and* loading `shellesc` works, without the need for the patch.