# MikTex crash when using LuaLaTex and glossaries-extra

Tags: luatex, miktex, glossaries-extra

I have an up-to-date MikTex installation with a newly-installed glossaries-extra. The MWE prints what I would expect, but MikTex crashes with little information in its log files. This is a serious problem in the actual system as the crash happens **before** the much larger PDF is shipped out, leaving me with nothing.  If anyone knows how to fix the MWE crash this will probably carry over into the actual system. The code is based on [glossaries automake not working lualatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468818/glossaries-automake-not-working-lualatex) but this question is not a duplicate.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}    

\usepackage{shellesc}

\usepackage[acronym, nomain, automake=immediate]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
    
\usepackage[HTML, hyperref, x11names]{xcolor}
 
\NewDocumentCommand\son{}{EnV}%
\NewDocumentCommand\sondesc{}{Le système est en vigueur [Ang : System On].}%

\newglossaryentry{son}{name={\son}, sort={SystèmeOn}, description={\sondesc}, first={{{\textcolor{Firebrick1}\son} (\sondesc)}}}%

\makeglossaries              
          
\begin{document} 

On utilize les sigles \gls{son} quand ...

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

The MikTex crash report is:

```
"Output written on mwe.pdf (1 page, 11221 bytes).
SyncTeX written on mwe.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on mwe.log.

Sorry, but texify did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\texify.log"
```

The MWE.log ends normally:

```
"\openout3 = mwe.ist
{C:/Users/XXXXX/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}] (./mwe.aux))


Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:" etc, etc.
```

Ditto for the MiKTeX-PDFTEX log:

```
"2022-11-01 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this is MiKTeX-PDFTEX 4.11.0 (1.40.24) (MiKTeX 22.10)                                                                 
2022-11-01 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands                                                                                         
2022-11-01 INFO  miktex-pdftex - UTF8 BOM detected: mwe.tex                                                                                           
2022-11-01 INFO  miktex-pdftex - executing restricted write18 shell command: makeindex "-s" "mwe.ist" "-t" "mwe.alg" "-o" "mwe.acr" "mwe.acn"          
2022-11-01 INFO  miktex-pdftex.core - start process: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c "makeindex "-s" "mwe.ist" "-t" "mwe.alg" "-o" "mwe.acr" "mwe.acn"" 
2022-11-01 INFO  miktex-pdftex - write18 exit code: 0                                                                                                  
2022-11-01 INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (29180) finishes with exit code 0"
```

The luahblatex.log ends with warnings:

```
"2022-11-01 INFO  luahblatex.core - start process: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c "makeindex "-s" "mwe.ist" "-t" "mwe.alg" "-o" "mwe.acr" "mwe.acn""

2022-11-01 INFO  luahblatex - this process (5220) finishes with exit code 0

2022-11-01 WARN  luahblatex.core - still open: C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex/data/le/luahbtex\luahblatex.fmt

2022-11-01 WARN  luahblatex.core - still open: mwe.pdf"
```

And the texify.log ends with fatal errors (which I'm not sure how to interpret)

```
"2022-11-01 INFO  texify.core - start process: luahblatex --synctex=1 C:/Bridge\mwe.tex 
2022-11-01 FATAL texify - The input file could not be found.                           
2022-11-01 FATAL texify - The input file could not be found.                           
2022-11-01 FATAL texify - Info:                                                        
2022-11-01 FATAL texify - Source:                                                      
2022-11-01 FATAL texify - Line: 0"
```

Comment: I never use texify and imho you gain nothing by using texify here, only bad error messages. I suggest to call lualatex directly. Apart from this, I could compile on miktex with the call `texify --engine=luatex test-utf8.tex`. The important part was the `.tex` at the end, without it it failed.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thanks for that.  I've been calling the system using LuaLaTex directly from within MikTeX with factory defaults.  Do you know what the settings for miktex-luahbtex.exe should be - I've played a bit with them and now have one that runs the MWE OK. But when I use it on the actual system it returns "This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.1 (MiKTeX 22.10)
 restricted system commands enabled.

Sorry, but C:\Miktex\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-luahbtex.exe did not succeed."  Which I don't understand at all.

Comment: don't try to use some internal miktex commands. Simply call lualatex. And don't call it with some absolute path, ensure that you are in the document folder and use `lualatex mwe`.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thanks for that. I've tried various things without success and now suspect that I may have have some version of the problem reported in github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/775 and tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632772/…. If so, what I need is a quick fix that would make the problem just "go away" without having to get into the internals of LuaLaTeX.

Comment: I suspect that you simply run into a new glossary bug: automake doesn't work currently. See the comments here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/663879/2388. It should be fixed in a few days. As a work-around run (e.g. in a terminal ) `lualatex mwe` and then `makeglossaries mwe`  and then `lualatex mwe` again.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thanks for that - it seems to have done the trick.  If you care to post an answer I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glossaries 2022/10/14 v4.50 has a bug which makes `automake` fail. Here you have to call `makeglossaries` on a command line manually to create the glossaries.

It has been repaired in 2022/11/02 v4.51. The new version is already in texlive, and miktex will follow soon. See also https://www.dickimaw-books.com/bugtracker.php?key=215