# Automake for Glossaries not working with Xelatex

Tags: xetex, glossaries

I am trying to make a glossary in Xelatex (I use Texworks and Miktex), but cannot get the glossary to print. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{verse}{name=verse,description={A bit of poetry.}}

\begin{document}

Here be dragons in a \gls{verse}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

I get the following warning:

> Package glossaries-extra Warning: Glossary `main' is missing on input line 13.

Line 13 being the \printglossaries command.

I also get the following output in my PDF:

> This document is incomplete. The external file associated with the
> glossary ‘main’ (which should be called GlossaryTest.gls) hasn’t been
> created.
> Check the contents of the file GlossaryTest.glo. If it’s
> empty, that means you haven’t indexed any of your entries in this
> glossary (using com- mands like \gls or \glsadd) so this list can’t be
> generated. If the file isn’t empty, the document build process hasn’t
> been completed.
> If you don’t want this glossary, add nomain to your
> package option list when you load glossaries-extra.sty. For example:
> \usepackage[nomain]{glossaries-extra}
> Try one of the following:
> • Add automake to your package option list when you load glossaries-extra.sty. For example:
> \usepackage[automake]{glossaries-extra}
> • Run the external (Lua) application: makeglossaries-lite.lua "GlossaryTest"
> • Run the external (Perl) application: makeglossaries "GlossaryTest" Then rerun LATEX on
> this document. This message will be removed once the problem has been fixed.

The .glo file has been created, and contains:

```
\glossaryentry{verse?\glossentry{verse}|setentrycounter[]{page}"\glsnumberformat}{1}
```

As you can see, I already have the first proposed solution. I frankly don't know how to implement either of the others, and am in any case looking to produce a simple, automatically generated glossary.

Comment: Your MWE work correctly without  warning.

Comment: This is why I'm a little confused - my MWE is essentially the same as some examples I found when looking for a solution. Could it make a difference that I use Xelatex, or is this not potentially relevant?

Comment: In my humble opinion, no.

Comment: Then what could the reason be? I'm still getting the same warning and no glossary.

Comment: Wait for some much better user than me to answer you.

Comment: I think there is a bug, at least in my version. glossaries adds commas to the list of types, and now it tries to automake `,main,` instead of `main` and that fails.

Comment: I added a bug report at the glossaries bug tracker.

Comment: see https://www.dickimaw-books.com/bugtracker.php?key=215

Comment: It sounds like the bug is fixed and the update should be available soon. In the meantime, calling \usepackage[automake]{glossaries}[=v4.49] is working. Thank you!